# remove facebook and twitter links in `bookdown` in R, Rmarkdown

Tags: r, knitr, bookdown

I am using the `bookdown` package in R to write a gitbook, but I don't want the final book to have the sharing links to facebook, twitter. I am using something like this in the `YAML`

```
--- 
title: "A Minimal Book Example"
author: "SN"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: 
  bookdown::gitbook
    gitbook_config:
      sharing:
        facebook: false
        twitter: false
documentclass: book
link-citations: yes
description: "This book ... ."
---
```

but I am getting an error

```
Error in yaml::yaml.load(enc2utf8(string), ...) : 
  Scanner error: mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 6, column 19
Calls: <Anonymous> ... yaml_load_utf8 -> mark_utf8 -> <Anonymous> -> .Call
Execution halted
```

Can anyone help me in setting options in `YAML` so that no sharing options show up in the final rendering?

thanks!
SN

Comment: I found how to change `YAML` metadata here - https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/html.html and changed the all the sharing options to 'no' and modified `all = []`, but I don't see any effect on the output. Is there any other way to switch off the sharing options or not them at all? Thanks!

Comment: I have the same issue. I cant remove these buttons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two mistakes:

1. You omitted a colon after `bookdown::gitbook`;
2. `gitbook_config` should be `config`.

```
--- 
title: "A Minimal Book Example"
author: "SN"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: 
  bookdown::gitbook:
    config:
      sharing:
        facebook: false
        twitter: false
documentclass: book
link-citations: yes
description: "This book ... ."
---
```

Comment: Thank you @yihue, I do have another question regarding sharing the gitbook which I have posted as another question. I would be very thankful if you could take a look at that one also.